# Connecting to WMTS of GeoServer from QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wms, wmts

I am trying to configure a WMTS using the version 2.5.2 of Geoserver. It seems to be quite straightforward.

The problem comes when I try to connect to the WMTS using QGIS 2.6.0. I have access to the Getcapabilities but when I add a layer the image is empty.

Comment: Do you know the version of the server? For instance INEGI ask to define vms versio 1.1.1, . I am able to use it by adding  ?VERSION=1.1.1 to the URL of the server. For instance: http://gaia.inegi.org.mx/NLB/mdm5.wms?VERSION=1.1.1

Comment: Hi Gerardo,Thanks for answering me!! Finally I solved the problem installing the last version of Geoserver (v2.6). I do not really understand how, but just doing this the WMTS was properly configured.